# Sencha extjs 5 displaying tree in West layout

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

I am using Sencha extjs 5. I am having trouble to load a tree menu in the west layout. I can't seem to display anything. Please assist.

Here is my Main.js code:

```
items: [

    {
        title: 'Navigation',
        region:'west',
        floatable: false,
        margin: '5 0 0 0',
        width: 200,
        minWidth: 100,
        maxWidth: 350,
        html: '<script type="text/javascript" src="app/view/app.js"></script>'
    }
```

Here is my app.js code:

```
Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
renderTo: 'west',
title: 'Simple Tree',
width: 300,
height: 250,
root: {
    text: 'Root',
    expanded: true,
    children: [{
        text: 'Child 1',
        leaf: true
    }, {
        text: 'Child 2',
        leaf: true
    }, {
        text: 'Child 3',
        expanded: true,
        children: [{
            text: 'Grandchild',
            leaf: true
        }]
    }]
}
});
```

Comment: You can't insert a script tag like that. Look at the component loader example for how to remotely load components.

Comment: Do you maybe have a link for the example? I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `renderTo` then `region` is not used. `region` is only used when you add component into container with border layout.
Another thing `Ext.getBody()` doesn't take any argument, so `Ext.getBody('west')` returns just body element of page. If you have element (eg. `div`) on page with `west` id, then use `renderTo: 'west'`.

Comment: Hi, thank you. I have done the changes as you requested. Still nothing showing.

Comment: I have updated my code. Please assist. I can't get any of my pages to display in my layout. I am having issues understanding the logic behind how to display pages.